# Orchard 1.6 - Error building web site in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: build, visual-studio-2012, orchardcms-1.6

Using WebPI 4.0 I have installed and run successfuly Orchard 1.6, then  for deploying purposes, I opened the web site in Visual studio 2012 and tried to build it but got the next:

1 error as next:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Orchard\Modules\Contrib.Cache\Contrib.Cache.csproj
>   1

the error points to the first line: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

and some warnings as next:

> The element 'PropertyGroup' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003' has invalid
>   child element 'MvcBuildViews' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'. List of
>   possible elements expected: 'Property, AllowUnsafeBlocks,
>   AppConfigForCompiler, ...

the warnings point to the different lines in the same file above.

I could find nowhere a similar case, any idea please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found that the WebPI downloads the already compiled version of Orchard CMS, so most of the source code is missing there, and it is wrong way to try to compile it again in Visual Studio.

The solution here is to cancel using the WebPI version and to download the source code version instead in a zip file from here:

http://orchard.codeplex.com/releases/view/90325#ReviewsAnchor